# i have a problem with pygame where im trying to run a partial output from VScode but its not displaying it.Please help me?

Tags: python, pygame

I have recently picked up pygame and i had decided to make a galaga type game with reference from different books. In the book they have mentioned that by that time i have written the code shown below, i should be able to see an ouput of my spaceship centered at the bottom of the screen.

Currently the only output shown is the PYgame version as well as the link to its contribute page. I have not been able to see the display yet. How to move forward with the above dilemma.Sorry if its a dumb question.

This is the code for the partial output below

import sys
import os
os.environ['PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT'] = "hide"

import pygame

from settings import Settings

from alienship import Ship

class Invasion:

```
def __init__(self):
    pygame.init()
    self.settings=Settings()
    self.screen=pygame.display.set.mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))

    pygame.display.set.caption("Sarangs RipOff Game")
    self.ship = Ship(self)

    self.bg_color = (255, 255, 0)
def run_game(self):
    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()

        pygame.display.flip()
```

if **name**=='main':

```
ai=Invasion()
ai.run_game()
```

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the code. Paste the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hello im a beginner to pygame - python too, but theres few things i might help. First of all move pygame.init() under to your modules. Secondly i dont think Ship(self) will work since its no atturibute to Invasion class's self. Make a main game function outside of the classes and redrawing window function at bottom which works while Run=true, and if you press Quit(x) run=false. Put some keys to move your ships with  pygame.key.get_pressed() i hope it helps. I strongly suggest you to watch some youtube tutarials about 'Object Oriented Python' and 'PyGame'.